# Converting analog voltage to drive interrupt signal in PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, pic, adc, microchip

I have a circuit that will output between 1v-4v when the circuit detect an event. When there is no event, the output voltage stays at 5v.

I want to use this as an interrupt input signal to my PIC18f4550 microcontroller so that when there is an event (i.e output voltage drop between 1v-4v), microcontroller will wake up and execute certain tasks.

Is there any simple circuit I can look into to convert this drop in voltage to 5v High digital signal that can be used as an interrupt input signal to microcontroller?

I do not wish to use analog input pins as ADC will requires constant polling to detect the change in input. I am looking for ways to work purely based on interrupts.

#### Update 1

I end up using comparator module and it is working fine. The only limitation was I could not use the internal comparator voltage reference module as it could not provide the reference voltage I need. I had to use additional wire with a simple voltage divider circuit to provide the necessary reference voltage. Otherwise, it works very well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PIC18f4550 has [analog comparator pins](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/31020a.pdf). You can supply an external voltage to defined the point at which they switch. An article about using them is [here](https://pic-microcontroller.com/how-to-work-with-inbuilt-analog-comparators-of-pic18f4550/).

Comment: I think this page has a better example -- at least it contains code and schematic: https://electrosome.com/analog-comparator-pic-microcontroller/  Should be mentioned that that comparators can generate interrupts. See the documentation starting on page 275 of the 4550 datasheet: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632e.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I understand your signal will normally be at 5V and when an event occurs it will drop to 4V or less.

I would try this:

[image]

When the input is 5V the output will be 0V.

When the input is 4V or less the output will be close to 5V. If the output voltage isn't quite high enough you can increase R1 a little (try increments of 2K.)

The circuit assumes that the input will either be at 5V or less than 4V. If it can hover between 4 and 5V then this is not a good solution.

Comment: Thank you. I end up using the comparator solution as i don't have a BJT on hand.